# How to use srcset and sizes for responsive images

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, retina-display, srcset

I have following snap-points: `480px`, `900px`, `1800px`, `2400px`.

and this markup:

```
<img
 sizes="(max-width: 2400px) 100vw, 2400px"
 srcset="
  boat-480.jpg 480w,
  boat-900.jpg 900w,
  boat-1800.jpg 1800w,
  boat-2400.jpg 2400w"
 src="boat-2400.jpg"
 alt="This is a boat">
```

How should I get responsive images to work?

Comment: Which iOS version is the iPhone running?

Comment: It's running the latest version, 9.2.1.

Comment: You may find this helpful - towards the end of the article https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Comment: @CarolMcKay, are you looking at the <picture> part about giving explicit instructions instead of doing what I have done, which is let the browser decide?

Comment: In the last paragraph under the "when?" Heading there are links to can-i-use, polyfills and one more.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, still early days I guess. I will play around with polyfill and see what I can make happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## 1. Basics

#### Device-pixel ratio

**Device-pixel ratio** is the number of device pixels per CSS pixel which is related to:

- Pixel density of the device (number of physical pixels per inch)
- Zoom level of the browser
  So, greater **Pixel density** and/or higher **Zoom level** results in higher **Device-pixel ratio**.

---

#### `srcset` attribute & `x` descriptor

On `<img>` tag, the `x` descriptor in the `srcset` attribute is used to define the **device-pixel ratio**. So in:

```
<img src="image.jpg" srcset="image-1x.jpg 1x, image-2x.jpg 2x, image-3x.jpg 3x">
```

- for a device-pixel ratio of 1, the image image-1x.jpg will be used.
- for a device-pixel ratio of 2, the image image-2x.jpg will be used.
- for a device-pixel ratio of 3, the image image-3x.jpg will be used.
- for the fallback the `src` attribute (image.jpg) will be used.

#### `srcset` attribute & `w` descriptor

If you want a different image on a larger or smaller viewport, the `w` descriptor in `srcset` and a new attribute (`sizes`) comes into play:

```
<img src="image.jpg" srcset="image-1x.jpg 200w, image-2x.jpg 400w, image-3x.jpg 600w">
```

This mentions that the width of the first image is `200px`, second image is `400px`, and third image is `600px`. Also, if the user’s screen is `150 CSS pixels` wide, this equates to the following in terms of `x` descriptors:

```
<img src="image.jpg" srcset="image-1x.jpg 1.33x, image-2x.jpg 2.67x, image-3x.jpg 4x">
```

#### `sizes` attribute

The actual implementation where you’d want a different size image (different height, width) on different screen sizes is accomplished by using `sizes` attribute along with the `w` descriptor of `srcset` attribute.

```
<img src="image.jpg" sizes="50vw" srcset="image-1x.jpg 200w, image-2x.jpg 400w, image-3x.jpg 600w">
```

If the browser width is `500 CSS pixels`, the image will be displayed `250px` wide (because of `50vw`). Now, this is equivalent to specifying:

```
<img src="image.jpg" srcset="image-1x.jpg 0.8x, image-2x.jpg 1.6x, image-3x.jpg 2.4x">
```

So, for a `1.5x` display, `image-2x.jpg` will be downloaded by a browser, since it gives a **device-pixel ratio** of `1.6x` (which is most suitable for a `1.5x` display).

## 2. Answering your question

You have mentioned that you have emulated a **480px** CSS width screen.

Because you have set `sizes` to `100vw`, that is equivalent to specifying:

```
<img src="boat-2400.jpg" srcset="
     boat-480.jpg 1x,
     boat-900.jpg 1.88x,
     boat-1800.jpg 3.75x,
     boat-2400.jpg 5x">
```

There is chance you have `3x` display, and thus the browser downloads `boat-1800.jpg` file.

**Questions**

> Oddly, when I tested this on Chrome on iOS the browser actually downloaded boat-2400.jpg which is even more worrying.

That would be due to the higher **Device-pixel ratio** of your iOS device, which is likely to be something near 5.

> Have I missed something here?

I dont think so.

> I imagine I don't need the sizes attribute because I have the image set to 100vw in all views

The value of `sizes` is `100vw` by default. But if you want to use `w` descriptor and want to have something other than `100vw` for your `sizes`, you need `sizes` attribute.